# Laravel - file path to UploadedFile instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, upload

I have a Laravel 4.2 API that, when creating a resource, accepts file uploads. The file is retrieved with
`Input::file('file')`

Now I want to write a script (also in Laravel) that will batch create some resources (so I can't use a HTML form that POSTs to API's endpoint). How can I translate a file path into an instance of `UploadedFile` so that `Input::file('file')` will pick it up in the API?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just construct an instance yourself. The API is:

http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html

So you should be able to do:

```
$file = new UploadedFile(
    '/absolute/path/to/file',
    'original-name.gif',
    'image/gif',
    1234,
    null,
    TRUE
);
```

**Notice:** You have to specify the 6th constructing parameter as TRUE, so the UploadedFile class knows that you're uploading the image via unit testing environment.

Comment: Using this approach, `$file->isValid()` returns false (because `is_uploaded_file()` returns false); therefore in the API I'm not able to pick the `UploadedFile` instance using `Input::file()`, and I also can't do `$file->move()`. Your answer pointed me in the right direction though, and with some minor adjustments in the API I managed to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You have to specify the 6th constructing parameter as TRUE, so the UploadedFile class knows that you're uploading the image via unit testing environment.

Comment: @Alexandros - It was marked as correct a year ago and upvoted, are you certain this is not just a quirk of your own code? Example: Can you prove this is required?

Comment: Yep I am sure. UploadedFile constructor is 
`public function __construct($path, $originalName, $mimeType = null, $size = null, $error = null, $test = false)`
 
If you dont pass $test as TRUE then phpunit tests are failing.

I think @AlexandreThebaldi had the same issued.

Comment: @Alexandros - looks like it is updated now. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 8):

```
  /**
   * Create an UploadedFile object from absolute path 
   *
   * @static
   * @param     string $path
   * @param     bool $public default false
   * @return    object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)
   * @author    Alexandre Thebaldi
   */

  public static function pathToUploadedFile( $path, $public = false )
  {
    $name = File::name( $path );

    $extension = File::extension( $path );

    $originalName = $name . '.' . $extension;

    $mimeType = File::mimeType( $path );

    $size = File::size( $path );

    $error = null;

    $test = $public;

    $object = new UploadedFile( $path, $originalName, $mimeType, $size, $error, $test );

    return $object;
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Here for **Laravel 8.x** based on Alexandre Thebaldi's answer:

```php
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;

/**
 * Create an UploadedFile object from absolute path 
 *
 * @param     string $path
 * @param     bool $test default true
 * @return    object(Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile)
 * 
 * Based of Alexandre Thebaldi answer here:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/32258317/6411540
 */
public function pathToUploadedFile( $path, $test = true ) {
    $filesystem = new Filesystem;
    
    $name = $filesystem->name( $path );
    $extension = $filesystem->extension( $path );
    $originalName = $name . '.' . $extension;
    $mimeType = $filesystem->mimeType( $path );
    $error = null;

    return new UploadedFile( $path, $originalName, $mimeType, $error, $test );
}
```

Comment: You can also get the mimeType using PHP `mime_content_type` function, like `mime_content_type($path)`